# Replacing missing values in time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, na, zoo

I am new to R. I was hoping to replace the missing values for X in the data. How can I replace the missing values of "X" when "Time" = 1 or 2 with the value of "X" when "Time" = 3 for the same "SubID" and the same "Day"

SubID: subject number

Day: each subject's day number (1,2,3...21)

Time: morning marked as 1, afternoon marked as 2, and evening marked as
3

X: only has a valid value when Time is 3, others are missing.

```
SubID Day  Time   X    
 1    1     1     NA
 1    1     2     NA
 1    1     3     7.4
 1    2     1     NA
 1    2     3     6.2
 2    1     1     NA
 2    1     2     NA
 2    1     3     7.1
 2    2     3     5.9
 2    2     2     NA
 2    2     1     NA
```

I was able to go as far as the following codes in zoo. I have very limited experience in R. Thank you in advance!

`data2 <- transform(data1, 
                   x = na.aggregate(x,by=SubID,FUN=sum,na.rm = T))`

Comment: Are you restricted to using the `zoo` package? I feel like this could be accomplished easily with `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks for responding! No, I don't have to use the zoo package, I just don't know how to do this with other packages or functions. How should I use `data.table` to achieve the result?

Comment: I'm on my phone but I think this works `library(data.table); setDT(data1)[order(-Time), Xf := zoo::na.locf(X), by=.(SubID, Day)]`

Comment: @josemz Thank you! The codes ran but nothing changes in the NA values. Any suggestions? Anything I missed?

Comment: The code should have added a new column `Xf` with the `NA`s filled. It didn't?

Comment: @josemz Yes, it does! This is how limited knowledge I have in R :( I don't even quite understand the code you gave me, especially this part: `Xf := zoo::na.locf(X)` But yes, it worked! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Don't know how large your time series is, but you could replace the na.locf function from zoo with the implementation from imputeTS. This might be a little bit faster. Just write imputeTS::na.locf(X) instead and/or library(imputeTS). Anyway zoo's locf implementation is already on the faster side - there are way slower locf implementations in other packages (e.g. spacetime::na.locf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the explanation of my comment:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(data1)
data1[order(-Time),
      Xf := na.locf(X),
      by = .(SubID, Day)]
```

Ok so the `setDT` function makes the `data1` object a `data.table`. Then `order(-Time)` orders `data1` with respect to `Time` in descending order (because of the `-`). `Xf := na.locf(X)` creates a new column `Xf` by reference (which means you don't have to assign this back to `data1`) as `na.locf(X)` which is a function in the `zoo` package that fills the NAs forward with the previous value (in this case filling 2 and 1 with the value in 3). The last line specifies that we want to do this grouped by `SubID` and `Day`.

Hope it's clearer now, feel free to ask if you have further doubts.

Comment: Can I ask a follow-up question? How can I fill the missing values of X when Time equals to 3 with the means of X for each SubID? What I should I add to the existing codes to make it work?  `data2 <- transform(data1, 
                   x = na.aggregate(x,by=SubID,FUN=mean,na.rm = T))`

Comment: Do you mean you have missing values in X where Time equals 3 and you want to fill them with the mean of the values in X where Time equals 1 or 2, for each SubID?

Comment: I mean I have missing values in X when Time equals to 3 and I would like them to be filled with the means of the values in other X when Time equals 3 (while ignoring the missing values in X when Time equals to 1 or 2)?

Comment: So if you want to use the same fill value for all records you can compute that value first: `fill_value <- mean(data1$X[data1$Time == 3], na.rm = TRUE)` and then you can use it to  fill the missing values where Time equals 3 like this: `data1[data1$Time == 3 & is.na(data1$X), "X"] <- fill_value`.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it. I have learned from much from your comments and explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the data by descending time and then use `X[1]`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(SubID=1, Day=1, Time=c(1,2,3), X=c(NA, NA, 2.2))

df <- df %>%
    group_by(SubID, Day) %>%
    arrange(desc(Time)) %>%
    mutate(
        X=case_when(
            is.na(X) ~ X[1],
            TRUE ~ X)
    )
```